# Angular Format Date ngModel value for sending to payload, i need format `31-July-21`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In angular 9 i want to format and send my date in payload in this format otgStartDate: `31-Jun-21`, but rigth now code is going to payload like this otgStartDate: `2021-07-20T09:56:39.000Z`

HTML code:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker-custom" [(ngModel)]="OnSiteStartDate" 
          placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" [minDate]="minDate"
          [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, showClearButton: true, clearPosition: 'right', showWeekNumbers: false, dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-default'}"
          bsDatepicker readonly />

Typescript:
OnSiteStartDate: any;
const payload={
 otgStartDate: this.OnSiteStartDate,
}
```

Comment: You chose a really bad example. Now it's not clear if you need `yy-mm-dd` or `dd-mm-yy`.

Comment: i need dd-mm-yyy

Comment: ok how to dispaly month name otgEndDate: "10-09-21" like 10-Aug-2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has a [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) function.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
//...
const payload={
 otgStartDate: formatDate(this.OnSiteStartDate, 'dd-MMM-yy', 'en-US'), // edit parameters accordingly
}
```

Also check [DatePipe custom format options](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) for more info.

Comment: ok how to dispaly month name otgEndDate: "10-09-21" like 10-Aug-2021

Comment: I edited my answer, it should now display: `13-Sep-21`